# addClass() doesn't work with getElementById in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to manipulate an element class within a directive. The directive is of a toolbar and it's supposed to add a class to 2 elements after some scroll.

1. The element directive itseld;
2. The view, to add/remove margin;

This is my `html` structure:

```
<ag-toolbar class="ag-toolbar--sec"></ag-toolbar>
<div ui-view="app" autoscroll="false" id="appView"></div>
```

And this is my directive:

```
function agToolbar($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var elView;
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                elView = document.getElementById("appView");
            }, 400);

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                if (this.pageYOffset >= 128) {
                    element.addClass('scroll');
                    elView.addClass('agMargin');
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('scroll');
                    elView.removeClass('agMargin');
                };
            });
        }
    };
}
```

In the console I keep getting the error:

> elView.addClass is not a function
>
> elView.removeClass is not a function

But the `element.addClass` is working fine. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addClass` belongs to `jqLite` (or `jQuery` if available), see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element.

That is, you need to wrap the DOM element in a `jqLite`/`jQuery` element:

```js
elView = angular.element(document.getElementById("appView"));
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Didn't knew about it, and since the console was showing the dom correctly, i didn't knew what to do.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Side question: why are you using `setTimeout()`? Whatever you're trying to achieve, it's quite dangerous, e.g. if the user scrolls before `elView` has been set.

Comment: I was still testing. But when I try to get the element (which is a ngView) it's still not loaded. Any way to fix this?

Comment: What if you put the `<ag-toolbar />` below the `<div />` rather than above?

Comment: Then the layout will not be as expected.